# How to make long oval shaped button with shadow in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, nine-patch

I want to make a button look like this.
[image: oval button].

I tried to make it using 9 patch image. But the shadow part doesn't look good.

Are there any method by which I can add shadows to 9 patch image?

Comment: You should post your current 9 patch so to let us see WHY it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For oval shape you can do is make a shape.xml with

```
<corners
android:radius="49dp"
/>
```

and set it as the background of the button. Eg- button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/angry_btn"
android:text="Button"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
android:shadowColor="#0022A8"
android:shadowDx="-1"
android:shadowDy="-5"
android:shadowRadius="13"
/>
```

buttonshape-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="49dp"
/>
<gradient
android:gradientRadius="100"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerY="50%"
android:centerColor="#47A891"
android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="radial"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```